# update multiple row with a query in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

Helo,
I am a beginner java programmer.
I need to update multiple rows with a query using mysql database and java codes.
I need to update the age field (data type int) in the database based on the current date. I believe I need to iterate and use the hasnext ... but I just unable.

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you have so far (post java code and SQL create table statements, for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update all the rows using a common logic based on current date, write a single update query and execute it. It will update all the rows. If logic is different then use updatble result set.

Comment: I am facing a problem with the iteration on integer array. I need the java code to do the iteration

Comment: share the problem you are facing.

Comment: String query = "update patient_details set PatientAge =?";
              try{ 
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
             
            
            stmt.setInt(1, AgeInYears());
             int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();null, ex);
            }
        }  
           
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing a problem in executing an update query or is it with the iteration on integer array. Please provide more details. And if you are attempting to update similar data, try doing it using a single query, as executing queries in loop is not recommended.

Comment: String query = "update patient_details set PatientAge =?"; try{ stmt = con.prepareStatement(query); stmt.setInt(1, AgeInYears()); int rowsUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate();null, ex); } } }

Comment: Don't you have a where clause in your query? This will update the same age in all the rows and you will be left with the last age entered reflecting in all the rows. Is that what you want? Could you please add some info on the source of AgeInYears()